# high quality daily data

Tags: equities, data, index

I am analysing some trading strategies, so lots of high quality data is needed. I have been using yahoo finance which provides a lot of high quality daily data on stocks and indices.

Currently I am interested in index data S&P500 total return and so on. I'd prefer total return data sets. Unfortunately yahoo finance doesn't provide data for a wide range of countries or at least not with the quality I want. I couldn't get complete data from danish stock market index from 1988 to 2017 for example.

So do you now any free data provider where I can get high quality data on stock markets?
my criteria are:

a) necessary

- Data must be correct
- as few gaps as possible (week ends and holidays is ok)
- daily data
- time frame ranges from approximately 1988 to 2017 (1 or 2 years less is still ok)

b) nice to have:

- Total return of the index

Comment: Are you able and willing to pay?

Comment: That's the point. As I said, the data should be free, since yahoo provides a lot of free data which serves well for my purposes. I am very unwilling to pay for more data since my analysis has come really far and I would only have broader but not deeper information. So, I am willing to pay 5 -10€ per month at most, but I doubt I achieve a lot with that amount.